# find the maximum sum subset array from an array such that its each powerset sum is not divisible by M and can consecutively choose at most K jumps?

Tags: arrays, sub-array

Given an array
A=[6,3,2,1,9,10,2,11]
My task is to select elements from the array such that sum of the elements which I pick should not be divisible by M=6 and I can skip at most K=2 elements consecutively. My final goal is to select the elements following above condition and get the maximum sum.

- means I am not picking

possibilities:

```
[-,3,2,-,9,-,2,11]=27
[-,3,-,1,9,10,2,-]=25
[-,3,-,1,-,10,2,11]=27
[-,-,2,1,-,10,2,11]=26
[-,-,2,-,9,10,2,11]=34
[-,-,-,1,9,10,2,11]=33
.
.
.
.
```

and the maximum answer is 34

any DP solution is appreciated